# Taking value from Timefield in a model and Using datetime operations on it.

Tags: python, django, datetime, time, timedelta

I am make an appointment booking functionality in an app. For that, I have start and end time of two work shifts. Using values from those two fields, I would like to find total minutes in each shift and then divide it into half hour slots. The problem that I have is this :

datetime library expects datetime objects to evaluate a timedelta but all I have are the TimeField. How do I convert TimeField to datetime.time value

Below is the model :

```
class ClinicMembershipAttribute(models.Model):
    DAY_CHOICES = (
        ('Monday', 'Monday'),
        ('Tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
        ('Wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
        ('Thursday', 'Thursday'),
        ('Friday', 'Friday'),
        ('Saturday', 'Saturday'),
        ('Sunday', 'Sunday')
    )
    clinicmembership = models.ForeignKey(ClinicMembership, null=True, blank=True)
    day = models.CharField(choices=DAY_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True, max_length=12)
    shift_one_start = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    shift_one_end = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    shift_two_start = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    shift_two_end = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_appointment_status_string(self):
        first_shift_delta = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1),self.shift_one_start) - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1), self.shift_one_end)).time()
        second_shift_delta = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1),self.shift_two_start) - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1), self.shift_two_end)).time()
        first_shift_seconds = first_shift_delta.seconds()
        second_shift_seconds = second_shift_delta.seconds()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.day + " - '"+str(self.shift_one_start) +" - " + str(self.shift_one_end) + "', '" + str(self.shift_two_start) +" - " + str(self.shift_two_end) + "'"
```

Error is in first_shift_delta and second_shift_delta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you don't need to worry about conversion DateField to datetime.time object. Django will make it for you when obtain data from DB. TimeField has [to_python()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python) method for this purpose.
You can check that TimeField returns datetime.time looking at [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2224).
I see only one problem in your code. If the value of TimeField() is Null you'll receive error message:

```
combine() argument must be datetime.time, not None.
```

Probaly you can add `auto_now_add=True` attribute to your fields and set `null=False, blank=False` to avoid such situation.
Try to run you code `datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1),self.shift_one_start)` has to work even if IDE says it contains error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) from the docs

A list of formats used to attempt to convert a string to a valid    datetime.datetime object.

If no input_formats argument is provided, the default input formats are:

```
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',   # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',       # '2006-10-25 14:30'
'%Y-%m-%d',             # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',    # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',       # '10/25/2006 14:30'
'%m/%d/%Y',             # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',    # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M',       # '10/25/06 14:30'
'%m/%d/%y']             # '10/25/06'
```

Try changing

```
shift_one_start = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

to

```
shift_one_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Hey Westly! when I try to first_shift_delta inside the datetime.combine function it's saying expected type 'time' , got 'TimeField' instead.

Comment: Try changing shift_one_start = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1),self.shift_one_start) - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1), self.shift_one_end)
```

return a `datetime.timedelta` object , you can use `total_seconds()` to get seconds then you can convert it to minutes